# Find element with multiple classes using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to get the h1 text "Mini Militia - Doodle Army 2 apk"
https://www.apkmonk.com/app/com.appsomniacs.da2/

I tried this but I got None

```
title = soup.find('div', class_='col l8  s8')
```

please Note there is multiple elements on the page that have classes "`hide-on-med-and-down`" and "`hide-on-large-only`"

```
<div class="col l8  s8">
        <h1 class="hide-on-med-and-down" style="font-size: 2em;">Mini Militia - Doodle Army 2 apk</h1>
        <h1 class="hide-on-large-only" style="font-size: 1.5em;margin:0px; padding: 0px;">Mini Militia - Doodle Army 2 apk</h1>
        <p class="hide-on-small-only" style="font-size: 1.2em;"><span class="item" style="display:none !important;"><span class="fn">Download Mini Militia - Doodle Army 2 APK Latest Version</span></span><b>App Rating</b>: <span class="rating"><span class="average">4.1</span>/<span class="best">5</span></span></p>
        <a class="hide-on-med-and-up" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'nav', 'similar_mob_link', 'com.appsomniacs.da2');" style="font-size: 1.2em;" href="#similar">(<b>Similar Apps</b>)</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
title = soup.find("h1", {'class':'hide-on-med-and-down'}).text
```

Comment: there is multiple elements on the page with this class 'hide-on-med-and-down'

Comment: in the given webpage there is only one such tag available.. I will update then code for multiple tags

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

There are two `<h1>` on site with same content only the class names are different, to control what size, ... should displayed on different resolutions

#### How to fix?

Cause content is identical, just select the first `<h1>` in tree to get your result, class names do not matter in this case, cause result is always the same:

```
title = soup.find('h1').text
```

#### Output

```
Mini Militia - Doodle Army 2 apk
```